# What is the the meaning of Coordinated effects in genetics?

Tags: genetics

I want to find the definition of **Coordinated effects**

in the paper enter the matrix [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168952518301240#bib0205) the author defines "Complex biological process" as

> coregulation or coordinated effect of multiple molecular species resulting in one or more phenotypes. Examples can range from activation of multiple proteins in a single cellular signaling pathway to epistatic regulation of development.

I gathered that **coregulation** refers to the **Transcription coregulator** [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_coregulator)

> In molecular biology and genetics, transcription coregulators are proteins that interact with transcription factors to either activate or repress the transcription of specific genes.

But the term coordinated effect eludes me. Does it refer to the Coordination complex? And what is the context in biology? Several papers mention the coordinated effect but fail to define what it is.

Biology and genetics are new to me; I need more understanding of the general field. Naturally, the term might be standard, but it is just puzzling.

Comment: You deliberately omitted the second half of the author's definition: "Examples can range from activation of multiple proteins in a single cellular signaling pathway to epistatic regulation of development." If you are right, that the term is only used by these authors, then what is your problem? Within this paper, just stick to the author's definition.

Comment: Quite the assumption that I deliberately did that. That I would say is quite presumptuous. Moreover examples are not definitions. They might outline key factors but this is no definition

Comment: You're right, examples are not definitions, they're usually better than definitions.

Comment: It's the definition the authors use in their glossary, which itself is defined to be a collection of definitions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary). Ergo you only provided half of their definition, which is a misrepresentation. I didn't say that you deliberately misrepresented the authors, simply that you deliberately omitted part of their definition. I don't see how you can argue against any of this.

Comment: Interesting point. My questions was not the term "Complex biological process" but the term `coordinated effect`. Even with brain krause comment an example is better than a definition. my argument still holds that the term `coordinated effect` is not defined in the paper and merely an example was given. Finally, arguing that examples are better do not help the reader understand the term. @acvill actually explained the term in the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Coordinated*, here, does not connote any special meaning above that of its English definition, nor is it referring to coordination complexes. Consider one of the definitions of *coordination* from [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/41066):

> Harmonious combination of agents or functions towards the production of a result

In your linked paper, the authors are using *coordinated effect* to refer to the cooperative or synergistic influence of multiple molecules or processes on a phenotype. I think this is most easily understood in contrast to the simple models of genotype-to-phenotype mapping that are often taught in introductory genetics courses, *i.e.* a single gene variant encodes a single factor that produces a fixed phenotype. A complex biological process is one in which the abundance, activity, and localization of different molecular components have an effect on the magnitude of a phenotype.

Comment: cheers! very well put. clear, concise and nicely outlined with comparison to the English dictionary. There are still concept that need to be explored but an overall great outline.